# Android LogCat sqlite syntax error meaning

Tags: android, database, sqlite, logcat, android-sqlite

I get the log cat error below:

```
 11-18 21:37:49.700: E/AndroidRuntime(19122): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Home1: , while compiling: SELECT _id FROM projects WHERE _name like Home1
11-18 21:37:49.700: E/AndroidRuntime(19122):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
11-18 21:37:49.700: E/AndroidRuntime(19122):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
11-18 21:37:49.700: E/AndroidRuntime(19122):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
11-18 21:37:49.700: E/AndroidRuntime(19122):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
11-18 21:37:49.700: E/AndroidRuntime(19122):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:127)
11-18 21:37:49.700: E/AndroidRuntime(19122):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:94)
11-18 21:37:49.700: E/AndroidRuntime(19122):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:53)
11-18 21:37:49.700: E/AndroidRuntime(19122):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
11-18 21:37:49.700: E/AndroidRuntime(19122):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1697)
11-18 21:37:49.700: E/AndroidRuntime(19122):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1582)
11-18 21:37:49.700: E/AndroidRuntime(19122):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1538)
11-18 21:37:49.700: E/AndroidRuntime(19122):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1618)
11-18 21:37:49.700: E/AndroidRuntime(19122):    at com.example.home_painter.DatabaseHandler.checkName(DatabaseHandler.java:334)
11-18 21:37:49.700: E/AndroidRuntime(19122):    at com.example.home_painter.MainActivity.addProject(MainActivity.java:37)
11-18 21:37:49.700: E/AndroidRuntime(19122):    ... 14 more
```

Is this due to "SELECT _id FROM projects WHERE _name like Home1" is not the correct syntax? I cannot seem to figure out the reason for this error.

Here is some code from my sqldatabaseHelper file:
Variables:

```
  // table name
private static final String TABLE_PROJECTS = "projects";
private static final String TABLE_IMAGES = "images";
private static final String TABLE_COLOR_MAP = "colorMap";
private static final String TABLE_COLORS_COLLECTION = "collection";

// Project Table columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "_id"; // Primary, integer
private static final String KEY_NAME = "_name"; // Unique, text
```

OnCreate method:

```
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    // FOREIGN KEYS
    String FOREIGN_KEYS = "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;";

    // PROJECTS TABLE
    String CREATE_PROJECTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PROJECTS 
            + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +" PRIMARY KEY("
            + KEY_ID + "), UNIQUE( "+ KEY_NAME + "))";

    // IMAGES TABLE
    String CREATE_IMAGES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_IMAGES + "(" + KEY_IM_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
            + IM_URI + " TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(" + KEY_IM_ID+ "))";

    // COLOR MAP TABLE
    String CREATE_COLOR_MAP_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_COLOR_MAP + "(" + PROJ_COLOR_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
            + COLLECTION_COLOR_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(" + PROJ_COLOR_ID + ") REFERENCES " 
            + TABLE_PROJECTS + "(" + KEY_ID + "), FOREIGN KEY(" + COLLECTION_COLOR_ID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_COLORS_COLLECTION
            + "(" + KEY_ID_COLLECT + "))";

    // COLLECTION COLOR TABLE
    String CREATE_COLORS_COLLECTION = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_COLORS_COLLECTION + "("
            + KEY_ID_COLLECT + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + COLLECTION_HEX + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLLECTION_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(" + KEY_ID_COLLECT + "), UNIQUE("
            + COLLECTION_NAME + "))";
    /*System.out.println(CREATE_PROJECTS_TABLE);
    System.out.println(CREATE_IMAGES_TABLE);
    System.out.println(CREATE_COLORS_TABLE);*/

    db.execSQL(FOREIGN_KEYS);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_PROJECTS_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_IMAGES_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_COLORS_COLLECTION);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_COLOR_MAP_TABLE);


}
```

onUpgrade method:

```
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    //Drop older tables if existing
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PROJECTS);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_IMAGES);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_COLORS_COLLECTION);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_COLOR_MAP);
    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Code i thought was relevant from a method where I get information from project.java to put into database:

```
values_PT.put(KEY_NAME, project.getName()); // project name
long project_id = db.insert(TABLE_PROJECTS, null, values_PT); // insert into database and save id for use
```

Code for checkName method:

```
  public boolean checkName(String name) {

    boolean resultName = false;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_PROJECTS, new String[]{KEY_ID}, KEY_NAME + " like " + name, null, null, null, null);

    if (c != null) {

        resultName = true;
    }

    return resultName;
}
```

Comment: The `Home1` in `_name like Home1` is an SQL identifier, you want a string pattern that LIKE will understand. Do some reading on placeholders, don't paste strings together to build SQL unless you know exactly what you're doing and you're very careful.

Comment: Another hint: `Home1` is an identifier, `'Home1'` is a string, and `?` is a placeholder that you can get the driver to replace with a properly quoted string. I don't know the Android libraries well enough to offer a real answer but that should be enough to get you started.

Comment: like this? 
`db.query(TABLE_PROJECTS, new String[]{KEY_ID}, KEY_NAME + "=?", new String[] {name}, null, null, null);`

Comment: I don't know the Android API off the top of my head but that looks like you're moving in the right direction.

Comment: @muistooshort if you post this as an answer I will accept it. It seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: There you go, I had to expand on the comments a bit to make me feel like I've earned it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL you're sending into SQLite looks like this:

```
SELECT _id FROM projects WHERE _name like Home1
```

SQLite is interpreting your `Home1` as a column name because, well, an unquoted string-ish value is an identifier in SQL. That's where your "unknown column" error comes from. You want something like this getting down to SQLite:

```
SELECT _id FROM projects WHERE _name like 'Home1'
```

or (probably) better:

```
SELECT _id FROM projects WHERE _name = 'Home1'
```

If you're not using `_` or `%` wildcards then LIKE is usually just an overcomplicated and expensive version of `=`.

How do we fix this? You could try manually quoting `name` but that's just silly in 2012, we have placeholders to push the quoting and escaping issues down into the database where they belong. I think you want to use something like this [`db.query`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) call:

```
db.query(TABLE_PROJECTS, new String[]{KEY_ID}, KEY_NAME + "=?", new String[] {name}, null, null, null);
```

The `?` placeholder will be replaced by the the value of `name` (properly quoted and escaped). Using a placeholder also helps protect you from SQL injection problems so it is a good habit to acquire.

Answer (score 0):

You use query:

```
"SELECT _id FROM projects WHERE _name like Home1"
```

However in your table PROJECTS there are no _id and _name columns. You have key_id and key_name. Therefore change the query to:

```
"SELECT key_id FROM projects WHERE key_name like Home1"
```

Comment: sorry I edited my question as I forgot to include the variables. KEY_ID = "_id"

Comment: But `Home1` is still a problem, see my comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

your query must be:

```
Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_PROJECTS, new String[]{KEY_ID}, KEY_NAME + " like ?",new String[]{"'"+name+"%'"}, null, null, null);
```